# Docker performance IO

Tags: performance, docker, io

I'm running a benchmark to test IO runtime differences between Docker containers and its host, and I noticed something strange. I've performed random writes/reads.
The storage driver for the container is `aufs`.

If the file to be written/read is smaller or equals to 1GB, docker is faster than the host (otherwise, if the file is bigger, docker is slower).
Why do I get those results for small files?

Comment: hava e look at http://www.draconyx.net/articles/some-docker-performance-tests.html